# Android 8.0 Oreo RunningServiceInfo returns 0 services

Tags: android

my Oneplus 5 just updated to Oreo and something has broken.
I have a simple widget which starts and stops some service.

But now, when I request List of services I got nothing

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningServiceInfo> service = manager.getRunningServices( Integer.MAX_VALUE );
Log.v( "ServCount", "size service: " + service.size() );
```

returns 0

Please help :'(

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices(int)):

> **This method was deprecated in API level 26.** As of O, this method is no longer available to third party applications. For backwards compatibility, it will still return the caller's own services.

So, if you do not have a service running, `getRunningServices()` will return an empty list on Android 8.0+.

Comment: So, is there any way to check if some others service is running? This service is road camera detector and I'd like to start/stop it using widget.

Comment: @FedorKryukov: "is there any way to check if some others service is running?" -- only for your own services, not those of other apps.